# Modify elements in list with ForEach lambda

Tags: c#, linq

I want to filter a string array:

```
string[] args
```

from the command line, e.g: "-command1 x y -command2 a b -command3 c d"

Taking all the words with a '-' at the beginning, then converting those to upper case.

```
var commands = args.Where(x => x.StartsWith("-")).ToList<String>();
commands.ForEach(x => {
    x.ToUpper()
    });
commands.ToString();
```

This will return the args list with words starting with '-' lower case - that is the lambda is not being applied. Why is this? Is a copy of the list being made for the lambda capture, and that is modified, not the origina list itself?

Comment: 1. You are not setting `x.ToUpper()` to anything. 2. But even if you did, it wouldn't compile: strings are immutable. You should do this: `var commands = args.Where(x => x.StartsWith("-")).Select(x => x.ToUpper()).ToList();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var commands = args.Where(x => x.StartsWith("-")).Select(y => y.ToUpper()).ToList();
```

or

```
var upperCommands = new List<String>();
var commands = args.Where(x => x.StartsWith("-")).ToList<String>();
    commands.ForEach(x => upperCommands.Add(
        x.ToUpper());
```

Comment: Why did you even need to mention the second option? The first one is a lot simpler and easier to read.

Comment: @ataravati : I completely  second what you said.. that mention was just for OP's understanding.

Comment: it's ok i got the first one. I didn't realise select was the method to use - i looked down the intellisense list and for some reason I got it confused with where's behavior, despite just using it!